# What's the meaning of the '&' character in the returned value?

Tags: java, generics

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

The part I'm interested in is this:  `return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Take a look at [15.16. Cast Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This means that the resulting value will be cast to `Comparator` **and** `Serializable` (i.e. a serializable comparator)

Note that when doing casts like this one, you're allowed to specify **only** one class (and infinite amount of interfaces), because it's not possible for a class to inherit from more than one super-class.

Comment: Cool.  Have never seen that before!  How long has that been a thing?

Comment: I don't know. Probably when casting was introduced as a feature in Java, which means 20 years :)

Comment: Well, in 15 years of Java, I've never seen that.  Learn something new every day.  :)

Comment: Me too. That's why I like SO. :)

Comment: It's explained in the [JLS - 5.5. Casting Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html)

Comment: I also code in Java for many years but haven't encountered such construct before! Thanks for the information

Comment: I think its Java 8, I changed compiler to 1.4 and got this: Multiple markers at this line
 - Additional bounds are not allowed in cast operator at source levels 
  below 1.8

Comment: Take a look at [15.16. Cast Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)

Comment: @CamelCamelius: Thank you! I see it and after the & should be an Interface type:  " & InterfaceType "