# And Operator to cast to some object in Java

Tags: java

Reading on how to composite lambda expression I came across the implementation of `comparing` static method of `Comparator` in java.util package.

```
  public static <T, U> Comparator<T> comparing(
            Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor,
            Comparator<? super U> keyComparator)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
        Objects.requireNonNull(keyComparator);
        return (Comparator<T> & Serializable) //WHAT DOES THIS MEAN ? AND WHY IT IS HERE ? 
            (c1, c2) -> keyComparator.compare(keyExtractor.apply(c1),
                                              keyExtractor.apply(c2));
    }
```

This is my first time I see a syntax like this one `(Comparator<T> & Serializable)`

What does this mean and why it is written like that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374083/whats-the-meaning-of-the-character-in-the-returned-value

Comment: What was -1 for ?, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

From [JLS §15.16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16):

> Casts can be used to explicitly "tag" a lambda expression or a method reference expression with a particular target type. To provide an appropriate degree of flexibility, the target type may be a list of types denoting an intersection type, provided the intersection induces a functional interface.

Its basically making the lambda class implement `Serializable` as well as `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

From Java 8 Specification [15.16. Cast Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16):

> If the cast operator contains a list of types - that is, a
> ReferenceType followed by one or more AdditionalBound terms - then all
> of the following must be true, or a compile-time error occurs:
>
> ReferenceType must denote a class or interface type.
>
> The erasures (§4.6) of all the listed types must be pairwise
> different.
>
> No two listed types may be subtypes of different parameterizations of
> the same generic interface.

So, it means that you want to cast return variable to one class and list of interfaces.